# Как вывести значение из массива в классе. При загрузке формы в dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```cs
namespace TestThree
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private MyClass clasMyClass;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class MyClass
        {
            private DataGridView dataGridView1;
            public int[] num = new int[0];
            public string[] strName = new string[0];
            public string[] strGroup = new string[0];
            private Random random;


            public MyClass()
            {
                num = new int[5];
                strName = new string[5];
                strGroup = new string[5];
                random = new Random();
                FillArray();
            }
            public MyClass(DataGridView dataGridView1, string[] array, string[] array1, int[] array3)
            {
                this.dataGridView1 = dataGridView1;
                this.strName = array;
                this.strGroup = array1;
                this.num = array3;
            }

            private void FillArray()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
                {
                    num[i] = random.Next(2, 13); 
                }
                strName[0] = "Ivan Klash"; strGroup[0] = "Іст-21д";
                strName[1] = "Tom Tor"; strGroup[1] = "Іпз-63а";
                strName[2] = "Edir Krahen"; strGroup[2] = "Kmi-44t";
                strName[3] = "Amanda Jeck"; strGroup[3] = "Top-64g";
                strName[3] = "Kenvi York"; strGroup[4] = "Home-16";
            }
        }      

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Group", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("GPA", typeof(int));
            
            for (int person = 0; person < clasMyClass.strName.Length; person++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(clasMyClass.strName, clasMyClass.strGroup, clasMyClass.num);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}

Я думал что может проблема из-за перегрузки констукторов класса но нет. Как именно вывести по колонкам эти массивы в dataGrid?
```